# "In order to select an item please sign in" issue occurring randomly when using Google Drive Picker UI

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-api, google-oauth, google-drive-picker

I'm using Google Drive Picker UI to select a folder and create or update spreadsheet into that folder on a schedule

Sometimes it works as expected but recently it is showing a message called "In order to select an item, please sign in". On clicking "sign in" button it shows "The feature you requested is currently unavailable. Please try again later."
Previously, this used to occur when reauthorizing immediately after revoking access but now I'm requesting with extra params like whom the folder is shared with, created date, folder name to display in front-end. It worked fine for some days but now, the issue above mentioned is occurring frequently.

```
  createPicker(oauthToken, authCode, authUser) {
    const googleViewId = window.google.picker.ViewId.FOLDERS;
    const docsView = new window.google.picker.DocsView(googleViewId)
      .setIncludeFolders(true)
      .setMimeTypes('application/vnd.google-apps.folder')
      .setSelectFolderEnabled(true);

    const picker = new window.google.picker.PickerBuilder()
      .addView(docsView)
      .setOAuthToken(oauthToken)
      .setDeveloperKey(this.props.developerKey)
      .setCallback(data => {
        if (data.action === window.google.picker.Action.PICKED) {
          this.fetchFolderDetails(data, authCode, authUser);
        }
      });

    if (this.props.multiSelect) {
      picker.enableFeature(window.google.picker.Feature.MULTISELECT_ENABLED);
    }
    picker.build().setVisible(true);
  }
  fetchFolderDetails(data, authCode, authUser) {
    window.gapi.client
      .init({
        apiKey: this.props.developerKey
      })
      .then(() =>
        window.gapi.client.request({
          path: 'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/' + data.docs[0].id,
          params: {
            fields: 'permissions, title, createdDate, shared'
          }
        })
      )
      .then(response => {
        let googleDriveData = {
          folderId: data.docs[0].id,
          mimeType: data.docs[0].mimeType,
          authCode,
          authUser,
          folderName: response.result.title,
          permissions: response.result.permissions,
          shared: response.result.shared,
          createdTime: response.result.createdDate
        };

        this.props.onChange(googleDriveData);
      });
  }
```

I expect to see the list of folders after authorizing.
[image]

[image]

*Update*
Adding a google drive scope somewhat fixed the issue but still the immediate reauthorizing issue persists.